# Debugging jQuery random variable issue

Tags: jquery, random

I built a jQuery random display module for a recent web project, but it has a bug. It's meant to fill 4 grid tiles with a random div element, with a button that will load 4 new tiles. Occasionally it will only display 2 or 3 and I'm not sure why.

See it in action at https://www.joytotheworldcoaching.com (About tab)

Here is the code:

```
//Randomizer on CLICK 

$('#btnRandomizer').click(function() {

         var classList = [".randomLittleThings", ".randomJesusBeats", ".randomJoyJams", ".randomFavorites", ".randomQuotes", ".randomPhotos"];
         var randomClass1 = classList[Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length)];
         var randomClass2 = classList[Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length)];
         var randomClass3 = classList[Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length)];
         var randomClass4 = classList[Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length)];

         var random1 = $(randomClass1)[Math.floor(Math.random() * $(randomClass1).length)];
         var random2 = $(randomClass2)[Math.floor(Math.random() * $(randomClass2).length)];
         var random3 = $(randomClass3)[Math.floor(Math.random() * $(randomClass3).length)];
         var random4 = $(randomClass4)[Math.floor(Math.random() * $(randomClass3).length)];


         var color = ["rgb(245, 171, 153)","rgb(254, 180, 123)","rgb(255, 126, 95)", "rgb(212, 14, 204)", "rgb(113, 58, 166)"];
            var randomHeaderColor1 = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
            var randomHeaderColor2 = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
            var randomHeaderColor3 = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
            var randomHeaderColor4 = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];

            $('.randomLittleThings').fadeOut('hide');
            $('.randomJesusBeats').fadeOut('hide');
            $('.randomJoyJams').fadeOut('hide');
            $('.randomFavorites').fadeOut('hide');
            $('.randomQuotes').fadeOut('hide');
            $('.randomPhotos').fadeOut('hide');

            $(random1).fadeIn('show');
               $('.randomLittleThings > .cardHeader').css({'background': randomHeaderColor1});
            $(random2).fadeIn('show');
               $('.randomJesusBeats > .cardHeader').css({'background': randomHeaderColor2});
            $(random3).fadeIn('show');
               $('.randomJoyJams > .cardHeader').css({'background': randomHeaderColor3});
            $(random4).fadeIn('show');
               $('.randomFavorites > .cardHeader').css({'background': randomHeaderColor4});

     });
```

It is supposed to display 4 fresh tiles each time the button is clicked but occasionally only displays 2 or 3. I'm wondering if it happens when the randomizer selects the same div twice.

Comment: Is something not correct with my answer? Let me know the issue and I can amend my code if needs be. :)

Comment: Hi Tiberiuscan, first of all thank you SO much for the reply, it is very insightful. I gave you an upvote but had to take off the accepted answer. I've been trying to work with it but I found that it isn't directly compatible with my markup. It's not practical for me to put all of the class elements into "classList" array because there are a huge number of elements. You gave me good food for thought though and I'm trying to rework it in my free time.

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3uLwpxe/)

Ok, I have changed quite a few things so I will try and go over each amend.

First of all, what I have created is a prototype of your version that fixes the problem at hand. It fixes the issue of cycling through all four divs and shows 4 entirely new different divs. But also includes other improvements such as dynamically creating new elements.

The first for loop is just creating a jQuery object from the list of divs mentioned in the array. Then, once all the current divs have been hidden, the next for loop is fired - appending the jQuery objects into the page. This is the part you'd want to focus on to add into your site. Check out the fiddle, as you can see, 4 new items are created every time and with no repeats. This is because when a div has been used, that div is removed from the `classList`.

I have done a lot of code tiding up too. For example, instead of targeting each element and telling each one to hide, I have targeted the surrounding container instead and found all divs within the container. I know this is not exactly what you might have set up in your website, but you can take the same concept. As you can see, this is far more succinct and saves you time from writing it all out.

I removed the elements too because if you hide them then they will remain in the DOM and will bloat up the page. So now you will always have 4 remaining within `.container`.

I have reused the colours so I will leave that up to you what you want to do with them. :) But you should be able to take this code and amend it for what you have.

```js
$('#btnRandomizer').click(function() {

  var color = ["rgb(245, 171, 153)", "rgb(254, 180, 123)", "rgb(255, 126, 95)", "rgb(212, 14, 204)", "rgb(113, 58, 166)"];
  var randomClass = [],
    jQueryObject = [],
    randomColor = [],
    classList = [
      "<div class='randomLittleThings'><div class='cardHeader'>Things</div></div>",
      "<div class='randomJesusBeats'><div class='cardHeader'>Jesuss</div></div>",
      "<div class='randomJoyJams'><div class='cardHeader'>Jams</div></div>",
      "<div class='randomFavorites'><div class='cardHeader'>Favorites</div></div>",
      "<div class='randomQuotes'><div class='cardHeader'>Quotes</div></div>",
      "<div class='randomPhotos'><div class='cardHeader'>Photos</div></div>"
    ];


  for (i = 0; i <= classList.length; i++) {
    randomClass[i] = classList[Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length)];
    classList = classList.filter(e => e !== randomClass[i]);
    jQueryObject[i] = $($.parseHTML(randomClass[i]));
  }

  $('.container div').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    createNewElems();
  });

  function createNewElems() {
    for (i = 0; i < jQueryObject.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < color.length; j++) {
        randomColor[j] = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
        $(jQueryObject).get(i).appendTo('.container').css({
          'background': randomColor[j]
        }).hide().fadeIn(250);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnRandomizer">
  Click me
</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="randomFavorites">
    <div class="cardHeader">
      Favourites
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="randomLittleThings">
    <div class="cardHeader">
      Things
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="randomJesusBeats">
    <div class="cardHeader">
      Jesus
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="randomJoyJams">
    <div class="cardHeader">
      Jams
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```